# concat two columns and search result

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to concat two columns in sqlite and perform a search on the concat column. Is this possible?

```
Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(
                "SELECT user_id,firstname,lastname, \"firstname\" || \"lastname\" AS val FROM "
                        + TABLE_DIRECTORY + " where val ='%" + text + "%'",
                null);
```

using sqlite and android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
   Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(
        "SELECT user_id,firstname,lastname, \"firstname\" || \"lastname\" AS val FROM "
                + TABLE_DIRECTORY + " where \"firstname\" || \"lastname\" LIKE '%" + text + "%'",
        null);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, firstName, lastName, FROM TABLE_DIRECTORY WHERE firstName || ' ' || lastName LIKE ?", 
                    new String[]{"%" + val + "%"});
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried, but as long as I remember, you have an error in your SQL:

```
Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(
        "SELECT user_id,firstname,lastname, \"firstname\" || \"lastname\" AS val FROM "
                + TABLE_DIRECTORY + " where val LIKE '%" + text + "%'",
        null);
```

text comparisons with wildcards use `LIKE`, not `=`

Comment: @Hades as I mentioned, I didn't try. Glad you finally found a solution! =)